# How to insert/replace string value into another string value at certain place?

Tags: string, replace, insert

This is an uploading tool. I am trying to rename a file name if it is existed in the folder already. 
The plan is to add a number after the file name. For example, if the file name is Hello.doc, it will be saved as Hello2.doc.

The problem is, the file name & file type are always different. It can be Goodbye.pdf/capture.png. I am not sure how to insert the number in the correct place.

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(savepath))
            {
                int counter = 2;
                while (System.IO.File.Exists(savepath))
                {
                    string newFileName = fileName + counter;
                    tempFileName = newFileName.Insert/replace //Not sure what to do here
                    savepath += tempFileName;
                    counter++;
                }
                FileUpload.SaveAs(savepath);
                lblUpload.Text = "A file with the same name already exists." + " Your file was saved as " + tempFileName;
            }
```

Does someone know? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please let me know if this is what you were looking for. Used StringBuilder to avoid creating new String objects after every concatenation.

```
String[] filepath = filename.split(".");
// filepath[0] -> filename
// filepath[1] -> extension

StringBuilder newFilename = new StringBuilder(filepath[0]);

// add number
newFilename.append(2);

// add period
newFilename.append(".");

// add extension
newFilename.append(filepath[1]);

return newFilename.toString();
```